# flutter: unhandled element pattern; Picture key: AssetBundlePictureKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#640cd()

Tags: flutter, dart

when I try to add SVG image file am getting an error like this

flutter: unhandled element pattern; Picture key: AssetBundlePictureKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#640cd(), name: "assets/images/nftt.svg", colorFilter: null, theme: SvgTheme(currentColor: Color(0xff000000), fontSize: 14.0, xHeight: 7.0))

```
- assets/images/
```

```
SvgPicture.asset(
  "assets/images/nftt.svg",
  width: 36,
  height: 36,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
```

Answer (score -1):

rather than using `"assets/images/nftt.svg"` try
•  `"images/nftt.svg"` or
•  `"nftt.svg"`

I encountered a similar problem and this happened out of nowhere, maybe due to changes in dart framework. But changing the above-mentioned path got the issue fixed.